# Study version of Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am interested in becoming learning to administer Windows Server 2008 (and possiby do a MCSE). I need a version to use at home but can't afford to buy it. Is there a free/cheap alternative?

If I wanted to learn Red Hat Enterprise Linux (and do the RHCE) I could download CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a student, you can take advantage of Microsoft's [DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/default.aspx) program which, if you qualify, gives you a free version.  You can also try their [virtual labs](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/virtual-lab.aspx), [test drives](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/test-drives.aspx), and [evaluation copies](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a program called "[DreamSpark](https://www.dreamspark.com/)". If you are enrolled in college/university you can get free copies of various MS products.